# Where can I buy iRobot Create?

Tags: irobot-create

I'm looking to buy iRobot Create, I can't find it on Amazon or any other place. I'm in Chile, would there be any shipping options?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Patricio, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a shopping question

Answer (score 1):

You can order them from [iRobot](https://store.irobot.com/default/create-programmable-programmable-robot-irobot-create-2/RC65099.html). I checked their site and it said they offer international shipping to Chile but probably your best place to start would be contacting [iRobot Customer Care](https://homesupport.irobot.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/200?_ga=2.56870574.566594270.1556022376-845279800.1556022376&_gac=1.83576548.1556022377.CjwKCAjw7_rlBRBaEiwAc23rhmC8LoGxmzGZodasLtoYvPDDNBwqW_NUulQs-1yx9GO0hU1OsufpchoC3cEQAvD_BwE).

Or just get any Roomba with a serial port and [make](https://www.irobotweb.com/-/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/Create_2_Serial_to_USB_Cable_Creation.pdf) or [buy](https://store.irobot.com/default/parts-and-accessories/create-accessories/communication-cable-for-create-2/4466502.html) the cable from the instructions on the iRobot Create website